# Converting from full path to tilde path for pushing JSX from Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, adobe, extendscript

I have a need to convert from a full path starting with `/Users/username/file.ext` to a tilde path `~/file.ext`. I see lots of ways built into `NSString` and `NSURL` that go from tilde to full but not the other way around. While I could go the route of using `NSHomeDirectory()` and replacing within the path string, I was hoping for a way baked into Cocoa for handling this should things change.

The reason why I need this is because I am pushing Adobe JSX scripts from a Cocoa app. The Cocoa app gathers all the data needed for the script and pushes the data as arguments to the script. The `File` class appears to require tilde-based paths (but not the `Folder` class which is odd), but I cannot find anything definitive in their own documentation and am going by my own observations. Full paths fail while tilde paths do not.

Comment: I don't think there is any Cocoa function for that purpose.

Comment: I didn't think so either, at least none that I could find in Apple's docs, but I wanted to be sure I covered everything before definitively concluding so.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but here is the answer:

```
let path:NSString // a file path
let pathWithTilde = path.abbreviatingWithTildeInPath
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1407943-abbreviatingwithtildeinpath

This method is available since macOS 10.0.